# Syntax error in MySQL Error #1064

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I'm trying to execute the following query:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE user_access
CREATE PROCEDURE check_user_login(IN username VARCHAR(50),IN `password` VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
SELECT 1
FROM user_access
WHERE UserName='$username' AND `Password`='$password'
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But getting this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE PROCEDURE check_user_login(IN username VARCHAR(50),IN `password` VARCHAR(' at line 2

What's wrong with the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `;` in two places.

```
DELIMITER $$
USE user_access; -- you missed the semicolon
CREATE PROCEDURE check_user_login(IN username VARCHAR(50), IN `password` VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SELECT 1
    FROM `user_access`
    WHERE UserName = username AND `Password` = `password`; -- you missed the semicolon
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like there's no separation between use `user_access` and `create procedure`, perhaps this will help you along:

```
USE user_access;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ...
```

also, your parameter syntax looks wrong to me, you don't want `'$username'` just `username` should do as it is the name of your parameter.

Comment: now i'm getting:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 6

Comment: here is the new query:
USE storedb;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE check_user_login(IN username VARCHAR(50),IN `password` VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
SELECT 1
FROM user_access
WHERE UserName=username AND `Password`=`password`
END$$
DELIMITER ;